# How can I show source code from .java file in html div?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am preparing website using html, php, js and I  need to show source code files (like .java,.xml) into html div as a part of my website.

Comment: did you try anything .. by the way you can show source code by using google

Answer (score 1):

Just like any other text file. Source codes are just text. Files with source code are just text files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

```
$file = file_get_contents('./people.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);


<div id="sourcecode"> <?= $file ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file_get_contents` for it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

As you say that you are using js in your website. Here is a solution for you using jquery. Hope that, this will help you show source code file  into html div.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="include"></div>
    <a style="display:none;" id="link" href="javascript:void(0);">Click Test Link</a>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#link").click(function() {
            $("#include").load("from.html");
        });
        $(function() {
            $("#link").trigger("click");
        });
    </script> 
</body>
```

`